# Where is clipboard location?

Tags: clipboard

Somebody said the contents in clipboard will be lost if I close the application where is the copy sauce, but in fact, if I right click on the selected texts from an application, click copy, now if I close the application where I copy from, You can still paste contents, so the contents in clipboard is must be stored in location or memory, I want to look at where clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a file with clipboard contents, unless you have a non-stanadard application that does so for you (It's built in with some desktop apps such as cairo-dock for example)

[A user on a ubuntu forum explains this perfectly here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729360/where-are-the-contents-of-the-clipboard-stored)

For reference:

> You seem to ben lacking an understanding of clipboards in linux. There
>   are 3 usually available to users.
>
> These clipboards are called "Selections"
>
> There is:
>
> - PRIMARY - This is normally used for middle mouse button = copy/paste
> - SECONDARY - Normally not used by much, but it exists. Usually as an in app specific copy and paste.
> - CLIPBOARD - Usually ctrl+c and ctrl+v style copy and paste.
>
> All of them are stored, by default in memory of the controlling
>   application (usually Xorg, but not always). And every child
>   application has access to it.
>
> Clipboard monitors and managers exist that can monitor the clipboards
>   and store their contents in a file, or more commonly, let you review
>   your clipboard history.

Comment: As before, I really want to know which program has accessed the  or read/write "Selections", any ideas to Xorg or other "Selections"?